# Referring to the same table while working in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm currently working on a dataframe requiring some alterations in many columns.
My code looks similar to this:

```
Table_A$Field_A <- "10"
Table_A$Field_B <- "20"
Table_A$Field_C <- "30"
Table_A$Field_D <- "20"
Table_A$Field_E <- "20"
```

It could be seen that it's repetitive. I think there should be a function or package that I can use to avoid typing `Table_A$Field_X` every time I work on different columns in the same dataframe.

I tried searching but I couldn't come up with the proper keyword to get the solution. All answer is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `data.table` and `dplyr` packages should work just fine. See : https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf

Comment: Or in base R take a look at `with` and `transform`

Comment: Or set alias for both tables and columns and use it

Comment: @MauritsEvers IMHO, *`within`* and `transform`, `with` would be less applicable to OP's question (I've understood that desire is to simply reference columns by names with least possible effort).

Comment: Rosette As a side point, please consider not storing integers as strings. Consider `pryr::object_size("20")` and `pryr::object_size(20)` results from the `pryr` package. It seems like you are starting with R; absorbing good practices and now when you learn may save you a lot of pain in the future.

Comment: @Konrad So in your opinion `transform` and `with` are less applicable but then you give a `transform` and `within` solution? Perhaps this is a typo in your comment otherwise this seems like an odd statement to make. For what it's worth: In my opinion, OPs question is *precisely* a case for `with(in)` and `transform`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Sorry, not the best wording on my side. To clarify: *`with`* is less applicable; *transform* and *`within`* are more applicable. *`Transform`* is synonymous to *`within`* but not to *`with`*. Broadly speaking, I wouldn’t recommend using *with* to transform the data as this function was designed primarily to facilitate simpler calls to model functions. My point is that `within(in)` is misleading as `with` and `within` differ; it's infrequent that there is *"a case for `with(in)`"* as usually one function is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using external packages have a look [`base::within`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/with) function. The function allows you to specify your data frame as `data` argument and undertake modification on variables using `expr` argument that takes an expression.

```
TableA <-
    as.data.frame(sapply(
        X = paste("Field", LETTERS[1:5], sep = "_"),
        FUN = function(x) {
            3
        }, simplify = FALSE
    ))

within(data = TableA,
       expr = {
           Field_A = 1e3
           Field_B = -10
       }) -> TableA
```

---

## Notes on comments

Please note that syntax for `transform` is different. To achieve the provided solution using `transform` you would do:

```
transform(TableA,
          Field_A = 1e3,
          Field_B = -10) -> Table_res_transform
```

This would be equivalent of:

```
within(data = TableA,
       expr = {
           Field_A = 1e3
           Field_B = -10
       }) -> Table_res_within

identical(Table_res_transform, Table_res_within)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

## `dplyr`

```
require(dplyr)
TableA %>%
    mutate(Field_A = 1e3,
           Field_B = -10)
```